# Notify on changes on a revised answer

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, votes

I came upon [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/860688/setup-windows-remote-desktop-on-port-80)

The least-voted answer, according to the comments, was downvoted because it's a "link-only answer".

(Kind of inconsistent, are we? The highest-voted answer is also a "link-only answer" but it has *positive* votes; the least-voted one had a *negative* post until I up-voted).

Now, checking the revision history, I saw that the answerer had edited his answer with very clear explanation. But ironically, **his answer still has lower vote than the "link-only" answer"**.

I'm thinking that such situation is because those who had downvoted the answer did not realize that the answerer had significantly revised his answer, to the point that it doesn't deserve a downvote but an upvote instead.

Is it possible to add a mechanism to notify downvoters that an answer has been revised, so the downvoters can change their vote?

Comment: related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8623/concept-of-conditional-downvotes

Comment: Its only been a few hours since the answer was edited.  I will downvote the link only answer but the answer you talk about still needs work in my opinion.